# How to output binary files in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I want to be able to output `0x41`, and have it show up as `A`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
my $out;
open $out, ">file.txt" or die $!;
binmode $out;
print $out 0x41;
close $out;
```

It outputs `65` instead of `A` in the resulting file. This is not what I want.

I also have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464195/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-perl), but I wouldn't transfer the answer over. `pack` a short results to 2 bytes instead of 1 byte.

Comment: I think the most important hint in the [perldoc of print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print) is: *Prints a string or a list of strings.* ... and not [numbers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values). That's why the binary mode of the file handle (although needed for binary data!) is a red herring regarding the binary interpretation. I have also fallen into this trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`chr(0x41)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html).

For larger structures, you can use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
pack('c3', 0x41, 0x42, 0x43) # gives "ABC"
```

Regarding your suspicion of `pack`, do go read its page - it is extremely versatile. `'c'` packs a single byte, `'s'` (as seen in that question) will pack a two-byte word.

Comment: AFAIK, `chr` will work for any byte value (0-255). It has a bit more complex relationship to Unicode. Still, `pack` is quite reliable, as you can tailor the template to what you need.

Comment: consider to use `pack('C', ...)`. Otherwise for values above 0x7f there is a warning "Character in 'c' format wrapped in pack" (although the output is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Use the chr function:

```
print $out chr 0x41
```

Answer (score 1):

pack need two argument: The first argument explain how *and* how many data have to be packed:

```
perl -e 'printf "|%s|\n",pack("c",0x41,0x42,0x44);'
|A|

perl -e 'printf "|%s|\n",pack("c3",0x41,0x42,0x44);'
|ABD|

perl -e 'my @bytes=(0x41,0x42,0x43,0x48..0x54);
         printf "|%s|\n",pack("c".(1+$#bytes),@bytes);'
|ABCHIJKLMNOPQRST|
```

you could even mix format in the 1st part:

```
perl -e 'printf "|%s|\n",pack("c3B8",0x41,0x42,0x44,"01000001");'
|ABDA|
```