# Perl using GD for graphic programming

Tags: perl, gd

gd.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use strict;
use GD;


my $image = GD::Image->newPalette(401,201);

my $gray = $image->colorAllocate(200,200,200);
my $red = $image->colorAllocate(255,0,0);
my $black = $image->colorAllocate(0,0,0);


#draw a field of polka dots with random diameters
foreach my $i (0..10) {
    foreach my $j (0..5) {
            my $d = rand(50)+1;
            $image->arc($i*40, $j*40, $d, $d, 0, 360, $red);
            $image->fill($i*40, $j*40, $red);
    }
}


#draw the text in black
my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4) = $image->stringFT($black, "/home/eugenep/arial.ttf", 48,0,40,120, "hello world");

#outline the text with a black box
$image->rectangle($x1-10, $y1+10, $x3+10, $y3-10, $black);

print $image->png;
```

and its not displaying anything but rather bunch of weird characters on command prompt.

anyone tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried writing the image to a file and then opening that file in something that understands PNGs? Your console is just doing what you're asking it to do.

Comment: ohh that makes sense. i didnt know if perl was similiar to java where it would create jframe ish automatically when i do GD::Image->newPalette(401,201) @muistooshort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error. A "bunch of weird characters" is a PNG file it has produced, but you cannot expect the console to display images.

Save the output of this script to a file (on Linux: `./yourscript.pl > file.png`; on Win you may need to save `$image->png` to a file), open the produced file in a browser or an image viewer, and you'll see the image.

Comment: is there a perl code version of saving the $image into a png file ?

Comment: Just open it (as a binary file) and write to it, as you would normally do. PNG is information as any other. If you don't know how to do that, see the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464195/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-perl) and just replace `pack('s<',255)` with `$image->png`.

Comment: hmm when i did open(my $out, '>:raw', 'sample.png') or die "Unable to open: $!";
print $out $image->png ;
close($out); it just gave me a red picture :O

Comment: Replace `arc` with `filledArc` and remove `$image->fill(...)`.